# How can I check a list of folders exist in a given path

Tags: c#, directory

```
string[] folderPaths = new[]
{
    "anim",
    "audio",
    "cleo",
    "custom_models",
    "data",
    "libraries",
    "models",
    "modloader",
    "movies",
    "SAMP",
    "text"
};

foreach (var folderPath in folderPaths)
{
    string[] Liste = Directory.GetDirectories(gameFolder);
    foreach (var item in Liste)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(folderPath + item))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All granted folders detected, you can join.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A not granted folder has been detected, you cant join.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }              
    }
}
```

Although there is all granted folder, I get the same error: "A not granted folder has been detected, you cant join."

Comment: Maybe try counting?

Comment: What is `gameFolder`?

Comment: GameFolder is my gta san andreas folder

Comment: does `folderPath + item` actually exist?

Comment: yes they exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be :

```
if (Directory.Exists(item + "\\" + folderPath))
```

This line `string[] Liste = Directory.GetDirectories(gameFolder);` will return directories with full path like `C:\\TEMP\\Publish` and you have just the folder name in `folderPath` variable.

Here is the full suggested code :

```
string[] folderNames = new[]
{
    "anim",
    "audio",
    "cleo",
    "custom_models",
    "data",
    "libraries",
    "models",
    "modloader",
    "movies",
    "SAMP",
    "text"
};

string gameFolder = @"D:\gta san andreas\";

foreach (var folderName in folderNames)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(gameFolder + folderName))
        MessageBox.Show(folderName + " Exists");
    else
        MessageBox.Show(folderName + " Not Exists");
    
}
```

Comment: thx but still not work

Comment: Please check manually in your `gameFolder` if `anim` really exists. Debug your code and see what is the value of `item + "\\" + folderPath` and check the path, no reason it will not work!

Comment: I tested, still not working. Screenshot;
https://prnt.sc/U02R0Y4J52HL

Comment: Your code is confusing, i see different variables in screenshot! I suggest you to debug your code and see the values of the variables. And I suggest to use the meaningful variable names like change `folderPaths` to `folderNames`

Comment: Thanks for helping Suman, but i tested your code. Result link is;
https://streamable.com/2uvbgr

Comment: Check the updated code

Comment: Your code is worked, thank you so much. If i waste your time sorry for that. But i want If there is a folder other than folderNames, I want a show error.